# How to fix click listener for button in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to send a js object to the backend using AJAX when a button click occurs, but it seems that the button click isn't working. I'm fairly new to JS and was wondering if someone could spot what is going wrong.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  annotations = []
  anno.addHandler('onAnnotationCreated', function(annotation) {
    annotations.push(annotation)
  });

  document.getElementById('done').addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert("works");
  });
});
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Poster 1</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url_for('static',filename='css/main.css') }}">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{url_for('static',filename='css/annotorious.css') }}">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/annotorious.min.js') }}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/main.js') }}"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <img class="annotatable" height="600" width="400" id="canvas" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/1.jpg') }}"></img>
    <a href="{{url_for('poster2')}}">Next Poster</a>
    <button type="button" id="done" onclick="onDoneClick()">Done</button>
  </div>
</body>
<script type="text/js" src="js/main.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not defining "anno" if that's your full code, maybe that's the error. (`anno.addHandler('onAnnotationCreated'` <- what is anno?).

Or maybe check on the console if jQuery is loaded correctly and you can use also:

```
$("#done").on("click", function() {
    alert("clicked")
});
```

Comment: I've checked that jquery loaded correctly on console. Im using a cdn

Comment: is the code u posted on ur question the FULL code ur using?

Comment: Also I'm sure anno works because I'm able to print the annotations array in my code. I've edited the html to include the API that I'm using

Comment: Have you tried the code i posted? using jquery with the .on("click")

Comment: The error is at:

annotations = []
 anno.addHandler('onAnnotationCreated', function(annotation){
  annotations.push(annotation)
 });
If u remove it, the click listener works. Check console please

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#done').click(function (){
        alert("works");
    });
});
```